# ¿Cómo es el pseudocódigo de un FOR?

Tags: bucle-for, pseudocódigo

Quería saber la forma en la que se hace el pseudocódigo con FOR:
Por poner un ejemplo, ¿como se haría en el siguiente Shellscript?

Gracias, espero que me podáis ayudar, ya que dudo de si es con hasta, mientras (creo que es un while), pero quiero tenerlo claro.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Introduce valor"
read A
for (( I=1; I<=A; I=I+1))
do
      echo "Número $I"
done
```

Comment: Las palabras que uses para un pseudo codigo no importan... ya que es eso, es mostrar lo que queres hacer en palabras claras.. y un for es lo mismo que un while o un do en pseudocodigo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Introduce valor"
read (A)
for (( I=1; I<=A; I=I+1))
do
      echo "Número $I"
done


Escribir("Introduce valor") 

Leer A

Para (I ;desde 1 hasta A; con paso 1) Hacer

      Escribir ("Numero I") 

Fin Para
```

Answer (score 2):

En pseudocódigo es así:

```
Iniciar Procedimiento

Para i desde 1 hasta A con paso 1 Hacer<br>
Escribir i
Fin Para

Fin Procedimiento
```